# Elasticsearch must_not filter not works with a big bunch of values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the next query that include some filters:

```
    {
        "from": 0,
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "filtered": {
                        "filter": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "idpais": [
                                                115
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "tipo": [
                                                1
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "must_not": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "idregistro": [
                                                5912471,
                                                3433876,
                                                9814443,
                                                11703069,
                                                6333176,
                                                8288242,
                                                9924922,
                                                6677850,
                                                11852501,
                                                12530205,
                                                4703469,
                                                12776479,
                                                12287659,
                                                11823679,
                                                12456304,
                                                12777457,
                                                10977614,
                                                ...
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "area": "Coordinator"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "company": {
                                                "boost": 5,
                                                "query": "IBM"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "topic": "IT and internet stuff"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "institution": {
                                                "boost": 5,
                                                "query": "University of my city"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "script_score": {
                    "params": {
                        "idpais": 115,
                        "idprovincia": 0,
                        "relationships": []
                    },
                    "script_id": "ScoreUsuarios"
                }
            }
        },
        "size": 24,
        "sort": [
            {
                "_script": {
                    "order": "desc",
                    "script_id": "SortUsuarios",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The must_not filter has a big bunch of values to exclude (around 200 values), but it looks like elasticsearch ignores those values and it includes on the result set. If I try to set only a few values (10 to 20 values) then elasticsearch applies the must_not filter.

Exists some restriction a bout the amount of values in the filters? Exists some way to remove a big amount of results from the query?

Comment: Have you use terms (notice the letter 's') instead of just 'term' without s?

Comment: @CodeNotFound thank you. thank you, I had never  noticed about the "terms" directive

Comment: @CodeNotFound yes, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`terms query` is used for passing a list of values not `term query`.You have to use it like below in your `must filter`.

```
  {
  "query": {
    "terms": {
       "field_name": [
          "VALUE1",
          "VALUE2"
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: As given in above question, `term` query was being used to matching list of values.We need to use `terms` instead

Comment: ok.. got your point..!! Its just a part of query.. not a query. but as you have given it will list out those records which are matching terms?? right?? and not those does which not match those terms??